# How do I animate to another tab from a button?

Tags: flutter, dart

My Flutter app structure is making it hard for me to make tab transitions.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQKtk.png)

**main.dart** controls the tabs on the top, and there is a separate **homeTab.dart** file that controls the page below the tab: [Annotated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIKtd.png)

I want to make it so that when the "Discover More" button at the bottom (which is made from **homeTab.dart**) is tapped, it animates to the second tab "Browse".

I added this to **main.dart**:

```
TabController tabController;

@override
void initState() {
  tabController = new TabController(length: 5, vsync: this, initialIndex: 0);
  getEmail();
}

changeTabToBrowse(){
    tabController.animateTo(1);
  }
```

The **changeTabToBrowse()** function works, but I can only call it from **main.dart**. I tried passing the function to **homeTab.dart** as a parameter, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: please provide your homeTab code.

Comment: You can pass the `tabController` to `homeTab.dart` and call `animateTo` from there. Another solution is to use a provider and `context.read` to get the `TabController` you have in `main.dart` from another widget.